# How to configure Auto Restart of mariadb when it get killed?

Tags: mariadb

How to auto restart of mariadb goes down when it get killed.
As of now i am using crontab which doesnot help as its checking every 1min and not every second is there any solution related to systemd?

Answer (score 0):

When installing from RPM or .deb packages on distributions that have switched to systemd a service is set up by default already.

If you are installing from a generic linux binarytarball a mariadb.service file is included in the archive, but needs to be installed manually.

See https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/ for details.

Or you could still use the classic mysqld_safe wrapper script, which starts mysqld for you and will restart it when "death of a child" signals are received, unless mysqld has been shut down gracefully with "mysqladmin shutdown".

See: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mysqld_safe/